# K8S\Kubectl: How can I change Kubernetes context namespace name?

Tags: kubernetes, devops, kubectl

Using

```
kubectl config get-contexts
```

I received a list of my account contexts in the format of :

```
CURRENT NAME CLUSTER AUTHINFO NAMESPACE
```

For one of them, I'd like to change its ns name.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use :
kubectl config set-context –current –namespace=you-NS

Or install an easy tool for managing contexts and namespaces
kubectx/kubens

> > kubens # list all ns

> > kubens your-NS # change ns

https://github.com/ahmetb/kubectx

Answer (score 0):

You can use `kubectl config set-context` to change configurations of context

Ex: `kubectl config set-context <context-name> --namespace=<namespace-name>`

For more information refer to this [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/#kubectl-context-and-configuration)